multi languaga form in django
I'm not good in English.
I have a project in Django using TranslatedFields. everything is OK but in custom admin panel I have some issues.
currently I have 2 languages but maybe more in future.
for now I write this code in my template:
{{ form.short_description_fa|as_crispy_field }}
{{ form.short_description_en|as_crispy_field }}

I want to do it in a way that don't need to write fields in all languages.
I write this template tag
def single_range(form, langs, index):
    c = len(langs)
    fields = []
    rng = range((index - 1) * c, (index - 1) * c + c)
    for f in rng:
        fields.append(list(form.fields.values())[f])
    return {
        'fields': fields
    }

{% for field in fields %}
    {{ field }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}

and I got this output from it:
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7ff7fddcad50>
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7ff7fddc8b10>

is there anyway to do it without repeating the code?

You can achieve this result by passing the form and languages to your custom template tag, and then dynamically generating the fields within the tag.
from django import template #import django template

register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('your_template.html')
def render_translated_fields(form, langs):

    num_langs = len(langs)
    fields = []
     for i, field in enumerate(form.fields.values()):
         if i % num_langs == 0:
             fields.append([form.fields[f"short_description_{lang}"] for lang in langs])

      return {
    'fields': fields
             }

Then, in your template (your_template.html), you can use this custom tag like this:
{% load your_custom_tags %}

{% render_translated_fields form ["fa", "en"] %}

prefer this: Forms in Django (if the issue persists)

now I got more of them!

It feels like the issue you're encountering is that the template is rendering the form fields as objects rather than their actual values. you need to access the field's value attribute
